# How to provide a callback with return value to the view in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, mvvm-light

Let's say I have a WPF UserControl with some custom code-behind logic. Now the view has to perform an action which needs to be confirmed by the user, but showing dialogs is - defined by MVVMLight - triggered from my ViewModel like this:

```
bool result = await DialogService.ShowMessage("Message", "Title", "Yes", "No", null);
```

... where `result` would be true if the user clicked on "yes". Now my question is: *How can I deliver callback results from my ViewModel to my view?*

Two options came to my mind:

1. I could make a a Dependency Property taking a `Func<bool>` that is called eventually, but this seems too hacky.
2. Maybe the logic implemented in my view is too complex and i should extract it to a class outside the view. A singleton instance of this object would "live" inside my ViewModel and be bound to the view via Dependency Property. But am I violating the MVVM pattern here?

Comment: You should implement navigation instead.

Comment: Talking about MVVM the View does never perform any action you are talking about. The View execute a command from the ViewModel, which calls the dialog and if true then the real action is done - but called from the ViewModel!

Comment: @Aybe can you explain your idea a little more precisely?